# HTTP session scoped EntityManagerFactory in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-entitymanager

I have a need of using separate `EntityManagerFactory` for each HTTP session in Spring 4. It is because of authentication by DB login-password.
So I make session-scoped `DataSource` and `EntityManagerFactory` like this:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public FactoryBean<EntityManagerFactory> entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();        
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("db");
    return factoryBean;
}
```

Then I try to inject it into singleton:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: scopedTarget.entityManagerFactory,entityManagerFactory
```

What could be done to inject it right?

Comment: No you don't need a session scoped object. Use a [`UserCredentialsDataSourceWrapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.html) and set the credentials on each request. Don't try to work with a session or other scoped entity manager. Or use the build in multi tenancy support for hibernate which also supports this out-of-the-box.

Comment: Oh! Wow. Could you write it as an answer? I'll then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need (or want) a session scoped `EntityManagerFactory`.

Either use a `DataSource` that supports setting credentials for the execution thread, like the [`UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.html) or use the [multi tenancy support](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html) that is build into hibernate.